# multithreading, inter-thread communication, synchronization

Tags: c++, multithreading

One class XYZ has 3 member variable x, y, z. There is vector of [N] XYZ objects.

There are 3 threads A, B, C, they can access any objects in the vector and any member variable of that object.

```
class XYZ
{
public:
double x;
double y;
double z;
};
```

std::vector with N elements, where N is fixed throughout the program.

**How to design the inter-thread communication  to achieve thread-safety and maximum efficiency, i.e., minimum blocking.**

Here is some of my thinking process, **please correct me if I am wrong**.

1. Divide vector in smaller vectors and encapsulate into each thread
   class, then use a message queue to pass data around. The problems
   are all 3 threads can access anywhere of the vector and objects
   member, therefore it is difficult to sub-divide and encapsulate.
   Message queue itself needs blocking, i.e., reader needs to be
   blocked when sender is adding to the queue.
2. Use atomic library to make access atomic, therefore avoiding
   blocking. The problem is atomic is OS dependent, i.e., some
   operation is considered atomic under Linux may not be atomic under
   Windows.
3. Mutex, add 3 mutex objects for each member variable, e.g., mutex_x,
   mutex_y, mutex_z. However, the problem is that mutex is noncopyable,

i.e., if we have a class like,

```
class XYZ_mutex
{
public:
double x;
double y;
double z;
boost::mutex mutex_x;
boost::mutex mutex_y;
boost::mutex mutex_z;
};
```

We can NOT have a vector of XYZ_mutex, because .push_back() is a copy constructor.

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you use three mutexes rather than just one? And your logic about not having a vector is wrong -- you can create a copy constructor for your class (it wouldn't copy the mutex, of course, but why would you want to do that?)

Comment: While "We can NOT have a vector of XYZ_mutex, because .push_back() is a copy constructor." is true, you could just have vector of `ZYX_mutex *`.

Comment: What do the threads A,B,C do to the vector?

Comment: You haven't defined "access". Is it read access, write access, or both?

Comment: The matter of efficiency is likely impossible to address at this level.  What sort of manipulations will your XYZ's be undergoing?  The answer to that question should dictate your sharing/distribution design.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz That's actually an interesting suggestion, supposing the vector is completely filled before all this starts.  When you copy, the copied element gets a new mutex (or set of mutexes), and when you assign, the target keeps its initial mutexes.  You'll probably end up constructing more mutex than needed, but they'll be destructed fairly soon afterwards, so this might not be a problem.

Comment: @JamesKanze That's a consequence of putting the mutexes inside the class, where they probably don't belong. You could make it work, but it would probably work poorly. In this case though, we don't know enough about the OP's application to give sensible advice. But my gut feeling is that it likely would create way too many mutexes, each protecting way too little.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I agree with your gut feeling:-).  But if such fine grained protection is appropriate, putting the mutexes in the class may be the correct solution.  (Maybe.  I don't think I've ever seen a case where such fine grained protection was appropriate, so it's hard to judge.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to consider what usage patterns and what consistency requirements your program has.

First and most important usage pattern is whether any of the threads needs to modify these structures. If not, you don't actually need any locking - just make sure the structure is populated before the threads start reading it.

If the threads do have to modify the structure, you need to consider consistency. You need to ask yourself, if there are any constraints, other than modifying an individual `double` value, that limit when one thread can see changes made by another thread.

Once you define that, start thinking if data can be split between threads in any way to reduce conflict between threads - even if it can't be completely eliminated, the answer the question whether it's better to keep three vectors of doubles, a vector of XYZ or some other organisation depenst on whether there will be some threads that access certain XYZ objects more often, or if there will be threads that access x members more often, while others access ys or zs more often etc.

If you can't say anything about the probability of accessing any member of any instance by any thread, it's hard to say how to best organise them. It might even be a good idea to place them on the heap so that they land in separate cache lines.

Overall, probably the best suggestion is to start by putting them in any data structure that's best suited for your needs (vector, map, set etc.), using a single mutex to synchronise the whole thing, writing your program and then testing if you experience a bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for option 1 (with a few changes, see below), simply because having a mutex for each item in the array is too costly.

So, it's a good idea to divide your array into smaller chunks, each protected by a mutex. Then, when a thread needs to access some part of the array, it can access another data structure that provides it with the mutex that it needs to lock depending on the interval in which the accessed item is (for example a hash table associating the index of the item with the mutex for that specific interval).

Comment: If he can isolate accesses, this might be a good idea.  If a thread needs to access one section in order to update another, however, it will need to acquire two locks, and avoiding deadlock is tricky (although it can be done).

Answer (score 1):

There is no one right answer.  The basic rules are:

1. Try to organize things so that no thread every requires more than one
   mutex.  Otherwise, you need some (usually non-obvious) solution to avoid
   the risk of a deadlock.
2. Try to keep each mutex for as short a time as possible.  If you can
   organize things so that there are n distinct arrays, each thread only
   accesses a single distinct array, and each distinct array is only
   accessed by a single class, this is optimal, since it means that each
   thread can act without locks, once it has acquired ownership of its 
   distinct array.  (It doesn't sound like this is the case, however.)

A lot will depend on how (and how often) the threads are accessing the
elements of the vector.

Finally, there are several ways of handling the problem of mutexes in
the `XYZ` object.  The most obvious is to use a recent compiler, which
supports move semantics; `std::mutex` is movable, and can be used in a
`std::vector`.  Failing that, you can use a `boost::shared_ptr<>` to the
mutex.

Comment: Thank you James, I figured out by using boost::shared_ptr after few days of research. Here is a pretty good article about it. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/smart_ptr/sp_techniques.html

Answer (score 0):

Use option 1. But also split the vector into 3 parts and allow each thread to work on its chunk in order to not interfere with the other threads. You can always use the length of the vector to create these virtual boundaries. Heck, you can have each thread with its own vector. Then when you do an insert into the vector, send your request through a "load balancer" so it inserts in the right vector (just go greedy). You could also use the balancer to rebalance the vectors, given that some thread is slower than the rest (move items from 1 vector to the others)